# InsecureBoot problem

Tags: boot, command-line, 20.04

I've switched from Win10 to Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. Whenever I boot it up the first thing that's written on the screen is "Booting in insecure mode". That doesn't happen on my desktop PC. In fact, I checked the UEFI settings before booting and it showed me that SecureBoot is enabled. Is it just Ubuntu glitch?
I tried writing the mokutil enable command into terminal, but it wrote that it was unable to do that. Probably because SB is already turned on.

Comment: I suggest to disable Secure Boot in BIOS. It is not about security. You won't see this message.

Comment: Didn't get what you meant. Please, explain.

Comment: I mean that the Secure Boot feature doesn't add security. It is about control by Microsoft. If you disable it in BIOS, you won't have to tinker with it any more.

Comment: You recieve the "Booting in insecure mode" message when Secure Boot is disabled in the BIOS.  You probably disabled Secure Boot to install video drivers or virtualbox, as I did. I also recieve this message on my ASUS machine.

Comment: @OrganicMarble If you disable from within Ubuntu, you get this message. If you switch it off in UEFI, then you won't.

Comment: @Pilot6 that has not been my experience. I switched it off in the ASUS UEFI interface.

Comment: So, again, it seems that SecureBoot is enabled (checked it in UEFI settings as I booted). But I see the message that says contrary.

Comment: Disable it and you shouldn't see the message.